# I'm having issues with my style in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm getting crazy with this matter and seems i can't find a solution.
I started a laravel project and i'm unable to get the css working correctly.

I have created a new file named `style.css` in my `resources/css`, than i have linked that file to my `app.css` with `@import 'style.css';`.

The app.css is linked in my app.blade.php with  `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Everything seems fine to my eyes, but the css in `style.css` doesn't work.

I've tried any solution that i know, and also looked several web pages and other older projects done but everything seems correct, probably is just because i'm really tired.

Does any one can help me to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Is the CSS file loading, if you open dev tools and look in the network panel do you see the CSS file? Also, can we see the contents of style.css, perhaps the issue is in your syntax rather than how you're loading it in laravel?

Comment: @Ameer thanks for replying. Yes the ` app.css ` is correctly loading. The file only contains a class with a background color as i was just initializing the project. ` *{
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
}

:root{
    --main-bg: #000936;
    --white : #ffffff;
}

/* navbar  */

.bg-custom{
    background-color:#000936 !important;
}

 `

Comment: Inside `app.css` have you tried `@import url("style.css")`

Comment: @Ameer yes i have tried it also but still not working....

Answer (score 0):

The path of the method asset() ends in the public folder

you need to compile app.css by run this command "npm run dev"

if don't install npm before run "npm install" first

Comment: Hello @azooz77758, of course i've done it. I have the npm run watch open but it doesn't work the same :)